# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract issue?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

Am trying to connect to Database table using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. To do this am following these steps

**Step1:** Created a class which extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

```
<?php
class Application_Model_DbTable_Albums extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

protected $_name = "zfalbums";

public function getAlbums($id){
    $where = "id = $id";
    $row = $this->fetchRow($where);
    $row->toArray();
    return $row;
}
}
```

**Step2:** Calling above class in controller, like this

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    ;

    $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
    $result = $albums->fetchAll()->toArray();
    print_r($result);
}
}
```

Step3: Accessing index controller by using local host url

However when try to run this controller following error is thrown

> Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Albums' not found in

Here is the my project structure

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Rename your file `Application_Model_DbTable_Albums.php` to `Albums.php` and make sure inside it you have something like this

```
    Class Application_Model_DbTable_Albums extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

}
```

Comment: @flex coz thats how Zend Autoloader works and save you from doing requre_once yourself.

Comment: Now class not found error is gone!. Thanks, but no data is returned from db. Any idea